# Command output to a file with batch scripting

Tags: windows, string, file, batch-file, stdout

I am trying to generate an xml file. I compare two images using a command which returns a number. But when I try to redirect its output to a file, it prints the number with a newline character.

```
        echo a.jpg >> "result.txt"
        compare -metric NCC "a.jpg" "b.jpg" "c.jpg" 2>> "result.txt"
```

Expected output like:

```
        a.jpg 1
```

But it outputs:

```
        a.jpg
        1
```

I tried to get the result from the command and tried to concatenate with the a.jpg but I couldn't have managed.

```
        for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in ('compare -metric NCC "a.jpg" "b.jpg" "c.jpg"') do set result=%%a
        echo %result% 
        REM outputs 1ECHO is off.
```

Comment: what does `for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in ('compare -metric NCC "a.jpg" "b.jpg" "c.jpg"') do echo test %%a` say?

Comment: It says 1ECHO is off but that means result variable hasn't been initialized right?

Comment: only one output line? I hoped there were two of them.

Comment: Yeah. Only one line. [link](http://s16.postimg.org/w3ehst76t/Untitled.jpg)

Comment: Sorry I tested the wrong cote btw. Your code outputs 1 only. But when I delete the `test %%a` part, the output stays same which is interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

now I know, what happens:

```
compare -metric NCC "a.jpg" "b.jpg" "c.jpg" 2>> "result.txt"
```

your desired output is on STDERR, not on STDOUT (very unusual). But `for` captures STDOUT only.

It should be possible do adapt the `for`construct, but it's simpler to use:

```
<nul set /p "=a.jpg " >> "result.txt"
REM this line writes a string without linefeed

compare -metric NCC "a.jpg" "b.jpg" "c.jpg" 2>> "result.txt"
REM this line appends the STDERR of the "compare" command to the line
```

Comment: That worked but why do we need `<nul`,what is the aim of using it? (I am new to batch programming btw)

Comment: `set /p` is intended to ask the user for input. We mis-use it for writing a line without linebreak; to simulate an empty user input, we redirect the NUL device to it. Try `set /p "x=Give me Input: "` You'll notice, that your input keeps on the same line, just after the "give me input" prompt. It's a bit like cheating, but works well and is commonly used.

Answer (score 2):

First command adds a newline. Use it like this to avoid it and get output in one line.

```
echo|set /p=a.jpg >> "result.txt"
```